# How to access this kind of Json using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

i am beginer in Jquery and javascript can any one help me to how to acces this kind of json data using jquery.if any one have idea to better way to access this data than please help me. this json data are come form remote url.

```
{
    "1": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "name1",
        "large_name": "http://critiques-demo.she.com/beauty/makeuptool/images/models/model1.jpg",
        "thumb_name": "http://critiques-demo.she.com/beauty/makeuptool/images/models/model1_thumb.jpg"
    },
    "2": {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "name2",
        "large_name": "http://critiques-demo.she.com/beauty/makeuptool/images/models/model2.jpg",
        "thumb_name": "http://critiques-demo.she.com/beauty/makeuptool/images/models/model2_thumb.jpg"
    },
    "3": {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "name3",
        "large_name": "http://critiques-demo.she.com/beauty/makeuptool/images/models/model3.jpg",
        "thumb_name": "http://critiques-demo.she.com/beauty/makeuptool/images/models/model3_thumb.jpg"
    },
    "4": {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "name4",
        "large_name": "http://critiques-demo.she.com/beauty/makeuptool/images/models/model4.jpg",
        "thumb_name": "http://critiques-demo.she.com/beauty/makeuptool/images/models/model4_thumb.jpg"
    },
    "5": {
        "id": "8",
        "name": "Name8",
        "large_name": "http://critiques-demo.she.com/beauty/makeuptool/images/models/model8.jpg",
        "thumb_name": "http://critiques-demo.she.com/beauty/makeuptool/images/models/model8_thumb.jpg"
    }
}
```

Comment: "if any one have idea to better way to access this data than please help me". What is your way ? What have you tried? Please post your current code to help improve it.

Comment: jQuery.each will help

Comment: i need simple way to access this remote json data @ryadavilli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [$.jsonParse](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to parse the json string then loop using [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

```
$.each(data, function(k, v){
    document.write(v['id'] + ' ' + v['name']+'<br />');
});
```

**Output:**

```
1 name1
2 name2
3 name3
4 name4
8 Name8
```

In above example `k` represents the key and `v` represnts value (each `object`) and in this case the first `key` and `object` is ( `"1"` is key and `{...}` is object )

```
"1": {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "name1",
    "large_name": "http://critiques-demo.she.com/beauty/makeuptool/images/models/model1.jpg",
    "thumb_name": "http://critiques-demo.she.com/beauty/makeuptool/images/models/model1_thumb.jpg"
}
```

Using `v['id']` you can retrive the `1`, `v['name']` will return the `name1` and so on. If you use [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) then you don't need to parse it because it'll be parsed by `jQuery` and you can use it like

```
$.getJSON('url', function(data){
    $.each(data, function(k, v){
        document.write(v['id'] + ' ' + v['name']+'<br />');
    });
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/emp24/)

Answer (score 1):

Once you've parsed the JSON, it's just a regular JS object:

```
for (var id in data) {
    var thing = data[id];

    console.log(thing.name);
}
```

Comment: but how to get data ?. i have remote url.

Comment: @AmitPrajapati: `$.getJSON`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for` loop.

```
for(i = 0; i <= dataJson.length; i++)
{
     console.log(dataJson[i].name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the numeric keys as arrays like

```
console.log(dataJson[1].id);
```